# Weird behaviour with strings and structs

Tags: c, string, struct, printf

I've been having problems with the code below, and i would like to understand why it doesn't work. I'm getting a weird behaviour when i directly use a string inside a struct, returned from a function.

The first printf works no problem, same with the second and the third one, but for some reason the last one goes in segmentation fault or just prints a random string. The problem doesn't show up if I try using a char pointer in the structure instead of an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    char string[23];
} Test;

Test func()
{
    Test nuovo = {5, "test"};
    return nuovo;
}

int main()
{
    Test test = func();
    printf("\n1: %d", func().value);

    printf("\n2: %s", test.string);

    printf("\n3: %s", &(func().string[0]));

    printf("\n0: %s", func().string);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
====================[ Build | test | Debug ]====================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug --target test -- -j 4
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test -BC:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 test
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test -BC:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles 2
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 CMakeFiles/test.dir/all
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/test.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\test.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target test
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/test.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe   -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g   -std=gnu90 -o CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.c.obj   -c C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\main.c

C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\main.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\main.c:17:19: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char[23]' [-Wformat=]
     printf("\n0: %s", func().string);
                   ^
[100%] Linking C executable test.exe
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\test.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\test.dir/objects.a
C:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\test.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\test.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\test.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\test.dir\linklibs.rsp
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
[100%] Built target test
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.6\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles 0
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/rober/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug'

Build finished
```

Comment: Add a newline on the end, otherwise the output is not flushed.

Comment: Can't replicate [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/BJEucxsJE), nor [tutorialpoint](http://tpcg.io/OEMphf)

Comment: When you do call `func()` as argument to `printf` a copy is returned, this copy will be a temporaty that should be valid until the end of the full expression. I'm thinking about if the end of the full expression is the end of the `printf` call or if (since varargs functions are a little special) it only covers the argument itself. I lean to the direction that it should be valid (the full expression is the full `printf` call), and the program you show us is not the actual program that crashes for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that would be a compiler bug, then. Those codes are Windows-style, I wonder if it's Visual C++ :)

Comment: @Roberto what's the compiler you're using?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks so much for the quick reply! I'm using MinGW

Comment: you should upgrade your gcc compiler. Using gcc on windows it works fine. As Someprogrammerdude hinted, this may be a compiler bug. which version (gcc --version) ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm using 6.3.0, and it's the exact program that crashes me

Comment: I forgot to add, i'm using C90 because my university wants me to use that version, so that might be the problem

Comment: damn, I'm using 6.2.1 :). Can you [edit] to show the compilation line.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not sure if i added the right thing, i'm using CLion, also i wanna be sure you read the comment above because i think that's the problem, if i try the same code with C11 it works normally

Comment: yes, we don't see the actual compilation command line. Maybe by using some cmake verbose flag?

Comment: The code you show isn't C90 compatible. The second case with mixing declarations and statements wasn't allowed until C99.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well, that sucks, thanks for your time!

Comment: And if I "fix" your program to be C90 compatible then I get a couple of warnings (that I don't get in C99 mode) indicating that this simply isn't allowed in C90. Build with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` and you should get them as well.

Comment: damn seems that `cmake` doesn't want us to see your compilation options: "Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.c.obj". The link details are irrelevant. Murphy's law at work

Comment: added the flags and removed the working part of the code and i'm getting just this warning 

C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\main.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\main.c:17:19: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char[23]' [-Wformat=]
     printf("\n0: %s", func().string);

Comment: C90 and C99 modes produce different assembly, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/DWmUcj). In C90 the compiler pushes onto the stack not the pointer to the string, but the whole memory behind the string, because it  is not converted to a pointer. But your code has many problems with C90 - comments, declaring a variable not as the first in the block.

Answer (score 5):

Under C90 `func().string` is not an lvalue, and a non-lvalue array doesn't decay to a pointer.

The compiler is telling you just that:

```
C:\Users\rober\CLionProjects\test\main.c:17:19: warning: format '%s'
expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char[23]' 
[-Wformat=]
     printf("\n0: %s", func().string);
```

This makes pretty much any use of `func().string` illegal. Don't do that.

I don't have a good edition of the C90 standard, but from what I gather, it should say something similar to this somewhere:

> 3.2.2.1 Lvalues and function designators
>
> [...] an *lvalue* that has type "array of type T" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to type T" that points to the initial member of the array object [...]

Comment: Out of curiosity, `&func().string[0]` works, is it illegal too?

Comment: @KamilCuk No it doesn't work, use `-pedantic-errors`.